# How to make 2 animate one by one

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

How to make 2 animate one by one, first execute scrollTop 1500px, after that execute scrollTop -1500px. Thanks.

```
$(function(){
    $('#content').animate({
    scrollTop:1500
   }, 300, function(){
    $('#content').animate({
    scrollTop:-1500
   }, 300);
});
});
```

Comment: @Cybernate, my code just execute scrollTop:1500 ,but the second can not work.

Comment: I was able see both the transitions as needed in Firefox.

Comment: I didn't change anything, I just used your code on this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try taking look at http://api.jquery.com/delay/ this might be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, scrollTop can't have negative value so just use `top` instead:

```
$(function(){
    $('#content').animate({
       top:1500
    }, 300, function(){
        $('#content').animate({
           top:-1500
        }, 300);
    });
})
```

Comment: Thanks, scrollTop can't have negative value, but I still need a scrollTop.